# How to read jmeter results in gitlab

Tags: jmeter, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am very new to JMeter. I just wrote a test in JMeter and added the script in .yml file to run it in gitlab. The test runs fine and generates the .jtl result file. But I can't figure out how to fetch it and read the results in gitlab.

My .yml file looks like this

```yaml
Load tests:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: load tests
  script:
    - cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin"
    - .\jmeter -n -t JmeterTest.jmx -l testresults.jtl
  only:
    variables:
      - $TESTTYPE == "loadtest"
```

Comment: sorry thought I accepted the answer already. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `.jtl` file as a Gitlab artifact, as described in [Job Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html).

Your .yml file would look like this:

```yaml
Load tests:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: load tests
  script:
    - cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin"
    - .\jmeter -n -t JmeterTest.jmx -l testresults.jtl
  only:
    variables:
      - $TESTTYPE == "loadtest"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - testresults.jtl
```

When your job succeeds, Gitlab will automatically store the file, where you can download and view it from the job-specific page:

[image: artifact download]

Comment: For those wondering, this solution does not provide any integration with the Gitlab load performance testing feature, where reports are made available in Gitlab widgets. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/load_performance_testing.html